# Include Google Maps V2 Map in Activity with two Framelayouts

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I got in my Android App an Activity with two FrameLayouts. I would like to include in the top framelayout the a map by using googlemaps v2. In the bottom framelayout i would like to implement a list. Every time when i add the fragment with the map, the map uses the complete screen and if i include a list into the second framelayout i get an nullpointer error.

This is the code how i include the fragment with the map:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_tour);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
GoogleMapsFragment googleMapFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment111_container,
googleMapFragment,"mapfragment");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();:
```

This is the layout of the activity

```
<FrameLayout  
      android:id="@+id/fragment111_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="40"
      />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment222_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@color/blue"
    android:background="@color/black"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Can anybody tell me whether this is possible and how can i do this? Maybe somebody can show my an example.

Comment: And the problem is what?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, if you want to put mapFragment on top of the frameLayout, and the ListView, you should put them all inside the FrameLayout. Also you might want to put a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout inside your FrameLayout, so that you can make the mapFragment above your ListView.

Sample XML:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <RelativeLayout>
      <Fragment android:id="+id/mapFragment"
                ....../>
      <ListView android:id="list"
                android:layout_below="+id/mapFragment"
                ...... />
   </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```